# CASE WHEN statement with multiple IS NULL conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 variables(sedol, cusip, isin).  I want the to pull in the SEDOL if it is available, if not then pull in CUSIP.  If CUSIP is also unavailable then pull in ISIN.

Below is the code I've written. The problem is that when CUSIP and SEDOL is unavailable it does not pull in the ISIN. I can't figure out where I may have missed something.

```
CASE
WHEN sedol IS NULL THEN cusip
WHEN cusip IS NULL AND sedol is NULL THEN isin

ELSE sedol
END
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: lol i just was thinking of [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) on another question just before seeing this. you can put `cusip`, `sedol`, `isin` and `sedol` in it and it'll return the first non-null value

Comment: Reminder: CASE expressions are evaluated one by one in the exact order they appear in code. For future references, if you check a column for NULL in first WHEN, then in second WHEN you can skip that checking, because if `sedol` would be NULL, it wouldn't even evaluate your second WHEN.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
COALESCE(SEDOL, CUSIP, ISIN)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of your operations are preventing the 2nd when condition from ever being executed. You would need to swap the when conditions.

You want to look into the `coalesce` function.